# Typescript styled components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I was trying to use typescript with styled components. I have a div inside which there is a input component.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
const Input = () => {
  return (<div>testing</div>);
};

const Main = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  & > ${Input} {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

But it is throwing this error on the console.

[image]

Error Log:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Input' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>'.
      Type 'typeof Input' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type 'Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ThemeProps<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': type, label, value
  Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & Props, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof Input' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & Props, any>>'.
      Type 'typeof Input' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & Props, any>>'.
        Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "onSelect" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & Props, any>>'.
          Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'.
            Index signature is missing in type 'Element'.  TS2769

    111 |   display: flex;
    112 |   height: 100%;
  > 113 |   > ${Input} {
        |       ^
    114 |     display: none;
    115 |   }
    116 | `;
```

Comment: Please share errors as text, instead of images, as text is more readable and searchable. That being said, does anything about [styled components typescript api](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) help?

Comment: Its hard to find through the docs so I posted. I even checked out github issues but I can't find the fix.

Comment: How input is implemented (minimal reproducible example)?https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwDkSaWAtAMYGQB26tMCRA3AFBvW1JwCStYAK7w4AXkQoMmAHTABwgAYL2nCN3gBZAIZyxEsjMzAAbgrZw4RhGFRbkALlwYAHuwsALdMADm7mI4BGAAYggFI3OAAyOAA+OAASAG9+IRgAXzhE8wtLYGtbBzhaNXQItLZlNiA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Input is basic component it wraps <input> inside a <label>

Comment: See above playground - there's no error with simple input

Comment: Okay, I am sorry, Input is a functional React component. I've also updated the code above.

const Input  =  () => {
  return (<div>testing</div>);
};

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700774/typescript-styled-components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use a [component CSS selector](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) like `& > ${Input} {...}`, when you wrap `Input` by the `styled()` factory function. Also make sure to add a `className` prop for `Input` and forward it to a DOM element, so styles get applied.

```
const Input = ({ className }: { className?: string }) => { // add className prop
  return <div className={className}>testing</div>;
};

const StyledInput = styled(Input)``; // create a wrapper for styled context

const Main = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  & > ${StyledInput} { /* works now */
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

Comment: I tried, but the className props for Input is undefined. I don't know whats the reason.

Comment: You can have a look at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-60700774-fvdc1) for a sample and comparison with your version.

Comment: Thank you. it is working now. Had some typo in the code.